Sketching phase diagrams from a system of coupled differential equations
Consider the following system of coupled differential equations for functions $x(t), g(t), y(t), h(t)$:
\begin{align}
    \frac{dx}{dt}=g+y
\end{align}
\begin{align}
    \frac{dg}{dt}=0
\end{align}
\begin{align}
    \frac{dy}{dt}=h
\end{align}
\begin{align}
   \frac{dh}{dt}=-y-g
\end{align}
I am asked to sketch two separate phase diagrams, one for each of the $(x,g)$ and $(y,h)$ planes ($g(t)$ has the interpretation of the particle's momentum in the $x$ direction, while $h(t)$ is the momentum in the $y$ direction). I've done this for the $(y,h)$ plane. Since by equation $(2)$ $g=const.$, there is a critical point at $(y,h)=(-g,0)$. I am however having trouble with the phase diagram in the $(x,g)$ plane. Since $\frac{dg}{dt}=0$, I'd expect there to be horizontal lines, however solving the system of equations shows that $x(t)$ goes something like $\sin(t)$. How should the $(x,g)$ phase diagram look like?

The variable $x$ is not constant, but time doesn't appear in the phase space $(x,g)$. Since $\frac{\mathrm{d}g}{\mathrm{d}x} = \frac{\mathrm{d}g/\mathrm{d}t}{\mathrm{d}x/\mathrm{d}t} = 0$, the variable $g$ doesn't depend on $x$, so that you will get horizontal lines, indeed.

We solve this system to get ideas (we need ICs to solve for the constants and can pick some randomly)
$$\begin{align} x(t) &=c_3+c_2 (1-\cos (t))+c_4 \sin (t)+c_1(\sin (t)-t) \\ g(t) &= c\\h(t) &= c_2 \cos (t)-c_1 \sin (t)-c_4 \sin (t) \\ y(t) &= c_1 (\cos (t)-1)+c_4 \cos (t)+c_2 \sin (t)\end{align}$$
If we numerically solve (pick some ICs) and then parametrically plot $(x(t),g(t))$, we get a line

We can then compare that numerical solution to the $(x(t),g(t))$ phase portrait (notice it is just a bunch a lines that represent different ICs)

If we numerically solve (pick some ICs) and then parametrically plot $(y(t), h(t))$, we get a circle

We can then compare that numerical solution to the $(y(t), h(t))$ phase portrait (notice it is just a bunch a circles that represent different ICs)

